# format sharepoint link with file path

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

In our office, we have everything stored on Sharepoint. A lot of the company is remote. When we need to share files, we can copy a link to a Team's message or an email. The problem is that the link does not show the file path, and documents can be 5 or 6 levels deep. For example, a file may be in

Models > 3D > Animated > In Development > Project 3

but the link does not show that. A document usually only moves a bit--such as from "In Development" to "In Production"--but then the link becomes useless. It also does not help when we know another file is going to be in the same folder because the link does not show the folder.

I have spent a couple hours doing some online searching, but I cannot find a way to get the link to be formatted to show the actual filepath the way a file does in File Explorer, such as

D:\Documents\Archives\A Critical Thinking Rubric.doc

Is there a way to get Sharepoint/Teams to show the filepath in a link?

About 2 hours googling for possible setting changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get the **full path with file paths** for both Teams and SharePoint.

Via **Teams**:

1. Check the **checkbox** of the file
2. Click on the **"i" icon** on the *top right corner*
3. Scroll down the **Details pane** until you see the **Path** field
4. Click the **Copy** icon to get the full file path
5. You should get something like thi`https://{your domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{your site name}/Shared%20Documents/01%20-%20General/Document.docx`

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy6U6.png]

Similarly in **SharePoint**, it will be pretty much the same steps as how it is in Teams

[image]

Comment: This won't work when the file changes folders, per the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the status ("In Development") to being a column in SharePoint like "Status", and then creating a View on the document library. That way, the users can easily see the "In Development" versus "In Production" items, but the actual file location will always be the same, so the link will always work. See here for more on how to do that : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9